# pass result ajax to blade with foreach

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am trying to pass the ajax response to my view and use it as a variable to foreach,I need it to update the quantity of bikes available on the dates selected by the user
the procedure I use is:
I take the selected data in the calendar, I pass them via ajax to my controller
from the controller I execute the queries on the database and return to ajax a json with the data.

the ajax data must be cycled to assign the corresponding quantities to the categories but I don't know how to pass this data to the view

my view

```
 @foreach ($category as $cat)
  <div class="col pb-5 m-1">
      <?php 
      
      
      $categoryId=DB::table('categories')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
          foreach ($categoryId as $key) {
 
              
              $quantity[$key->id]=DB::table('bikes')->where('category_id','=',$key->id)->count('*');
          }
      ?>
      <div class="card cat m-auto position-relative " id="cat{{$cat->id}}" > 
          @foreach ($qty as $item=>$val)
          @if ($item==$cat->id) 
          <p class="m-3" id="numberqty" style="font-weight: bold;color:#ce2e30;text-shadow: 2px 5px 3px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.92);">{{-- x{{$val}} --}}</p> 
          @endif
          @endforeach
          <p class="check position-absolute" style="display: none"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>

          <input class="cat-id" type="number" value="{{$cat->id}}" hidden>
          <input class="id-cat" type="checkbox" name="category[]" id="category" value="{{$cat->id}}" hidden>
          <img class="card-img-top p-3" src="{{asset('storage/'.$cat->cover_image)}}" alt="">
          <div class="card-body my-n3">
              <h3 class="card-title text-center" style="text-shadow: 2px 5px 3px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.92);">{{$cat->tipo}}</h3>


                      
                  {{-- <h3 class="card-title">Disponibilità: {{$val}}</h3> --}}
                      
                          <button class="btn btn-primary pl-5 pr-5 ml-5 drop"  type="button">{{__('payment.page.price')}}</button>

                          <button class="btn btn-primary pl-5 pr-5"  type="button">Dettagli</button>

              
              

              <div class="show-drop" style="display: none">
                  <h3 class="text-center my-1">{{__('payment.page.price')}}</h3>
                  
                  <p class="text-center">    {{__('payment.page.1day')}} {{$cat->base}} </p> <hr>
                  <p class="text-center">     {{__('payment.page.2day')}} {{$cat->twoDay}}</p> <hr>
                  <p class="text-center">     {{__('payment.page.3day')}} {{$cat->threeDay}}</p> <hr>
                  <p class="text-center">    {{__('payment.page.4day')}} {{$cat->fourDay}}</p> <hr>
                  <p class="text-center">   {{__('payment.page.5day')}} {{$cat->fiveDay}}</p> <hr>
                  <p class="text-center">     {{__('payment.page.6day')}} {{$cat->sixDay}}</p> <hr>
                  <p class="text-center">   {{__('payment.page.7day')}} {{$cat->sevenDay}}</p>
                  <p class="text-center">   {{$cat->overprice}} {{__('payment.page.overprice')}}</p>
                  {{-- <p>{{$cat->overprice}}</p> --}}

              </div>

              
          </div>

      </div>
      <div class="number-drop" style="display: none">
          <label for="quantity{{$cat->id}}">Nome</label>
          <input name="{{$cat->id}}" type="number" id="quantity{{$cat->id}}" class="form-control" value="0" >
      </div>
  </div>
  @endforeach
```

my ajax

```
    $('#range_date').on('change', function(){
        
        var data = $(this).val();
        var split = data.split(' - ');
        var startDate = split[0];

        var dayStart = startDate.substr(0,2);
        var monthStart = startDate.substr(3,2);
        var yearStart = startDate.substr(6,4);

        var startCorrect = monthStart+"/"+dayStart+"/"+yearStart;
        console.log(startCorrect);



        var endDate = split[1];
        var dayEnd = endDate.substr(0,2);
        var monthEnd = endDate.substr(3,2);
        var yearEnd = endDate.substr(6,4);

        var endCorrect = monthEnd+"/"+dayEnd+"/"+yearEnd;
        console.log(endCorrect);


        var  date1 = new Date(startCorrect);
        var  date2 = new Date(endCorrect);
        var  diffTime = Math.abs(date2 - date1);
        var  diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 


        $.ajax({
            
            "url": "bookingCheck",
            "data": {
                "start": startCorrect,
                "end":endCorrect
                
            },
            "method": "GET",
            success: function (response) {
                let res = response;
                let qty = res['qty'];

                console.log(qty);
                
               document.getElementById('numberqty').innerHTML=qty;
                $('#numberqty').html(qty.html);

            }
        });
    });
```

my controller

```
    public function checkBike(Request $request){
        $date1=Carbon::parse($request->start)->format('Y-m-d');
        $date2=Carbon::parse($request->end)->format('Y-m-d');
        

        $contract=DB::table('contracts')->get();
        $contractdate=DB::table('contracts')->whereRaw('? between data_inizio and data_fine', [$date1,$date2])->get();

        if (count($contractdate) > 0) {

            foreach ($contractdate as $key) {
                $id=$key->id;
            }
            $bikeContract=DB::table('bike_contract')->where('contract_id','=',$id)->get();
    
            foreach ($bikeContract as $key) {
                $bikeselect[$key->id]=DB::table('bikes')->where('id','=',$key->bike_id)->get();
                
            }
    
            foreach ($bikeselect[$key->id] as $key) {
                $idcat=$key->category_id;
                $quantity=DB::table('bikes')->select('category_id')->whereNotIn('category_id',[$idcat])->get();
            }
            foreach ($quantity as $key) {
                $qty[$key->category_id]=DB::table('bikes')->where('category_id','=',$key->category_id)->count('*');
            }
            return response()->json(["qty"=>$qty]);
        } else {
            $categoryId=DB::table('categories')->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
                foreach ($categoryId as $key) {
            
                    $quantity[$key->id]=DB::table('bikes')->where('category_id','=',$key->id)->count('*');
                }
        return response()->json(["qty"=>$quantity]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
success: function (response) {
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  let qty = response.qty;
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this solution, but I cannot do a foreach on a variable that has not been created yet, in this case $ qty has no value yet, it should take the value of ajax after the call

Comment: What do you mean it hasn't been created? Your ajax calls the controller function, which returns the $qty.

Comment: sorry i'm still in the early stages, it actually returns a json

Comment: Yes, the controller returns the data in JSON format, that's what's supposed to happen. Then you use JS to parse the JSON and update your HTML with the data.

Comment: if i use your code i get an error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'response' has already been declared

Comment: i tried to change the name of the first variable
calling her
let res: now generate this error
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token or in JSON at position 1

Comment: Try `console.log(response);` before `JSON.parse(response)`, and see if the data returned by your controller function is correct. It should be an array such as `['qty' => 4893]`, in JSON format.

Comment: `let res = JSON.stringify(response);
                let respons = JSON.parse(res);
                let qty = respons.qty;` quello che torna è `{1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 2}` dove "1" id category and "2" quantity avaiable

Comment: I need to pass this object as a data to cycle in the foreach of the view, what could I do?

Comment: I removed the "let" from "let response" in my answer, you don't need to make more variables. You don't need so many variables. If these values are the quantities that you need then you process them via JS like this: `response['qty'].forEach(function(quantity,id) { $('#cat'+id+' .destination-tag').text(quantity); });` for the values to be replaced in the correct locations in your view.

Comment: thank you for your patience, it is very important for me to understand where I am wrong.
I need before the parse to convert the reponse to string `let res = JSON.stringify(response);
                let respons = JSON.parse(res);`, if I don't, it fails to do the parse response, also the last answer you gave me returns an undefined value

Comment: thanks for the help, with your suggestions I was able to solve, i changed the foreach to the equivalent for jquery `$.each(respons['qty'],function(id,quantity){
                   $('#cat'+id).text('Disponibilita: '+quantity); 
                });` and everything worked :)